# Creating a Factory with type checked parameters in Typescript 3.0

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I'm really excited about the new extractable parameter lists in TS 3.0 and as a way of learning how it works I wanted to create a Factory.

I have got this working:

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(paramOne: string, paramTwo: number, paramThree?: boolean) {

    }
}

class Factory<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>{

    constructor(private constr: T) { }

    create(...params: T extends new (...args: infer P) => infer R ? P : never): T extends new (...args: infer P) => infer R ? R : never{
        return new this.constr(...params);
    }
}

const myFactory = new Factory(MyClass);

const instance = myFactory.create("hello", 55);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(paramOne%3A%20string%2C%20paramTwo%3A%20number%2C%20paramThree%3F%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Factory%3CT%20extends%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%3E%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20constr%3A%20T)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20create(...params%3A%20T%20extends%20new%20(...args%3A%20infer%20P)%20%3D%3E%20infer%20R%20%3F%20P%20%3A%20never)%3A%20T%20extends%20new%20(...args%3A%20infer%20P)%20%3D%3E%20infer%20R%20%3F%20R%20%3A%20never%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this.constr(...params)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myFactory%20%3D%20new%20Factory(MyClass)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20instance%20%3D%20myFactory.create(%22hello%22%2C%2055)%3B)

This is pretty cool but the definition of the create() function is a bit long and contains a certain amount of duplication. I tried to simplify this:

```
create: T extends new (...args: infer P) => infer R ? (...args: P) => R : never = (...params: P) => {
    return new this.constr(...params);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(paramOne%3A%20string%2C%20paramTwo%3A%20number%2C%20paramThree%3F%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Factory%3CT%20extends%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%3E%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20constr%3A%20T)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20create%3A%20T%20extends%20new%20(...args%3A%20infer%20P)%20%3D%3E%20infer%20R%20%3F%20(...args%3A%20P)%20%3D%3E%20R%20%3A%20never%20%3D%20(...params%3A%20P)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this.constr(...params)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myFactory%20%3D%20new%20Factory(MyClass)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20instance%20%3D%20myFactory.create(%22hello%22%2C%2055)%3B)

This has errors as you can see in the playground:

> Type '(...params: any) => any' is not assignable to type 'T extends new (...args: infer P) => infer R ? (...args: P) => R : never'.

and

> A rest parameter must be of an array type.

Is there a way of making this shorter, simpler declaration work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a value to a conditional type when some type arguments are stil unknown is usually problematic, so I would not go that route.

To simplify the signature I would use the predefined `InstanceType` type and define a special type to extract the constructor arguments

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(paramOne: string, paramTwo: number, paramThree?: boolean) {

    }
}

type ConstructorArguments<T> = T extends new (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never

class Factory<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>{

    constructor(private constr: T) { }

    create(...params: ConstructorArguments<T> ): InstanceType<T>{
        return new this.constr(...params);
    }
}

const myFactory = new Factory(MyClass);

const instance = myFactory.create("hello", 55)
```